# C# why isnt my StreamReader working?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# StreamReader input files from labels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13172171/c-sharp-streamreader-input-files-from-labels)

Okay I am working on a Roller Dice program still, I need the program to show the previous High Score everytime the game starts over. However when I type in the code. Its giving me errors staying. The name 'File' does not exist and namespace name StreamReader could not be found?
Please help

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    try
    {
        int scores;
        int highscore = 0;
        StreamReader inputFile;

        inputFile = File.OpenText("HighScore.txt");

        while (!inputFile.EndOfStream)
        {
            scores = int.Parse(inputFile.ReadLine());

            highscore += scores;
        }

        inputFile.Close();

        highscoreLabel.Text = highscore.ToString("c");

    }   
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have added `using System.IO` as the namespace to import?

Comment: I'm agree with @Steve could be the import

Comment: You really need to invest in a tool like Resharper.  It will save you many trips to SO.

Answer (score 4):

Probably you haven't added the namespace import

```
using System.IO;
```

as an alternative you could write the full qualified reference to File and StreamReader objects

```
 System.IO.StreamReader inputFile;
 inputFile = System.IO.File.OpenText("HighScore.txt");
```

but, of course, this is not very convenient.

Also, please note, that if, for whatever reason your code throws an exception while reading the stream, then the method exits without closing the stream. This should be avoided at all cost.
[The using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) could be of help.

```
int scores;
int highscore = 0;
using(StreamReader inputFile = File.OpenText("HighScore.txt"))
{
    try
    {
         while (!inputFile.EndOfStream)
         {
             scores = int.Parse(inputFile.ReadLine());
             highscore += scores;
         }
         highscoreLabel.Text = highscore.ToString("c");
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
     }
}
```