# C# StreamReader input files from labels?

Tags: c#, streamreader

I have been using a `StreamReader inputFile` code from a `ListBox` and it works great, However, I would like to input the data from the `.txt` file into a `Label` box instead, is this possible? This is the code I tried and it gives me an error description stating

```
Use of unassigned local variable 'total'
```

```cs
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
      int total = 0; 
      int highScore;
      StreamReader inputFile;
      inputFile = File.OpenText("HighScore.txt");
      while (!inputFile.EndOfStream)
      {
          highScore = int.Parse(inputFile.ReadLine());
          total += highScore;
      }
      inputFile.Close();
      highscoreLabel.Text = total.ToString("c");
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
  }
}
```

Comment: the code looks ok, convert StreamReader inputFile = File.OpenText("HighScore.txt");

Comment: @Floradu88 I do not really think that this is a problem. `inputFile` was already defined in the next line. Have a great day :)

Comment: it is stating "Input String was not in a correct format" pop up error

Comment: I see that `total` was already defined with the number `0`. Are you defining more than ONE variables with the name `total`? Have a great day :)

Comment: @user1784476: Hang on, that sounds like you've now got a different error - that's an *execution time* error, which you wouldn't be able to get while you'd got a compilation error. (It would be caused by a line not being an integer, of course.) The code you've given *does* compile, so it's really not clear what you're doing at this point.

Comment: Everything Jon said... you can't get a format-exception (runtime) if it doesn't compile ("use of unassigned local variable"). The format-exception just sounds like an invalid string going into `int.Parse`.

Comment: Please post an example of that text file.

Answer (score 3):

The message you are seeing ("Use of unassigned local variable 'total'") relates to "definite assignment", which would be the scenario:

```
int total; // note not yet assigned a value

...

total += {whatever}
```

However, in the code you post, it *is* definitely assigned (initialized to zero). Therefore, I suspect that either the error message has been mis-copied, or the code sample is not a direct copy of the failing case.

Answer (score 1):

**The error is not in the code!** 
It is in the format of the text file! If there are any characters other than integers, the code will generate this error - " Input string was not in correct format"  (I guess by int.Parse() method!)